# Gerund form of verb "to empire"

Tags: verbs, gerunds

Is the conjugation "empiring" correct?

I cannot find references to that in dictionaries...
Still it makes sense to me, as "to empire" is a verb.

So could I say, "this dynasty had been empiring for over a century" ?

Comment: Nope.  But you could say ""this dynasty had been *building an empire* for over a century"

Comment: Consider using other verbs instead, e.g. *had reigned*, *had ruled (that part of the world)*, *had occupied the throne*.

Comment: Running an empire is also correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Empire* is not a verb in English. It is most commonly a noun and very occasionally an adjective.

Comment: Thanks! I was tricked by going at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empire and by scrolling without noticing to the French section "empirer" which has  "empire" for some tenses / persons.

Comment: It might be a little more correct to state that "empire" is not *normally* a verb; it could in principle be verbed, but this is not particularly likely to happen, especially because its verb forms would be quite confusing and unnatural-sounding.